# Does this FAQ accurately convey the mission of DIY.SE?

Tags: business-writing

The [DIY](http://diy.stackexchange.com) stack exchange is currently trying to make our [FAQ](https://diy.stackexchange.com/faq) more useful to new users, and I wondered if some folks from this community could take a look and help us to define ourselves better.

[This](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372/does-the-site-require-a-more-descriptive-faq-to-clarify-which-topics-are-on-topic/374#374) is the suggested rewrite of the [FAQ](https://diy.stackexchange.com/faq).  Here is the full version:

> For questions related to home improvement and repair, including:
>
> - Questions you would typically ask a home contractor (or Bob Vila, Mike Holmes, etc)
> - Questions on tools, materials, designs, and best practices
> - Questions to help identify the source or cause of a problem within your home
> - Questions about national building codes
>
> Questions you should not ask include:
>
> - Decorating advice
> - Local building codes or other advice limited to your specific city
> - Questions about contracts with builders and rental agreements
> - Questions not related to the home, including hobby projects, cars, and landscaping

We are trying to define ourselves as **the** place to go for Home improvement advice, specifically for folks who want to do the work themselves.  We are mainly a group of people who are good with tools, but not so good with words (as you might be able to tell).

Comment: This is an older question. It's been bumped by the system because it's been retagged, as per [this](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/534/26) meta post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I really like that you open with "Questions you would typically ask a home contractor." That's a great way to get across, very simply, what type of questions you deal with. You avoid needing to define specifics (though you do that to); instead, you're focusing on the *type* of expertise you're offering, which I find very appropriate.

Very minor rewrite suggestions - consider:

- `Questions you should not ask include:` into `We do **not** deal with the following topics:`
- `Questions not related to the home, including hobby projects, cars, and landscaping` into `Questions not related to home improvement projects (such as hobby projects, cars, or landscaping)`

You might want to include something about pricing being off-topic.

All in all, though, I think this FAQ presents its points in a clear and straightforward manner.

Answer (score 2):

The FAQ does a good job. That being said, I'd be tempted to suggest that the "what questions not to ask" be the FIRST part of the FAQ.

Of course, who reads FAQs unless that is the last recourse, anyway?

Comment: I disagree. "Questions TO Ask" should be first. First you say what's allowed/encouraged, and then you further hedge by saying what's specifically forbidden.